# How to remove repeated day from mysql datetime using php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Following php scripts

```
 <?php 
echo date('D, F d ', strtotime($event->starttime)); echo $this->timestamp(strtotime($event->starttime));    
?>
```

display result as,

```
Mon, March 21 Mon at 8:00 AM

Fri, March 25 Fri at 9:00 AM

etc
```

Unfortunately its showing day (Here, Mon and Fri) twice. Here how to remove the second day( ie, before string `at`). 
I would like to show output as

`Fri, March 25 at 9:00 AM`

Any help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo strftime('%a, %B %d at %I:%M %p', strtotime($event->starttime));
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two echoes for this, one echo is enough. You can add the 'at' text yourself, if you prepend it with a backslash.

From the [PHP Date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
<?php 
echo date('D, F d \a\t H:i A', strtotime($event->starttime));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lowercase d passed to date() should return only the day number... check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for a list of all the valid parameters.

Try removing the space following d?